# シェルを使ってyyyymmdd形式の変数をunixtimeに変換したい。

Tags: shellscript, unix

シェルを使ってyyyymmdd形式の変数をunixtimeに変換したい。

起きてる問題として変数に格納するとエラーが発生します。

```
date +%s --date "2005-01-01 00:00"
結果
1104505200
```

直のstringならエラーは起きないが、変数だとエラーが出る。

```
unitime='2005-01-01 00:00'
date +%s --date $unitime
結果
date: extra operand ‘00:00’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

### やりたいこと「yyyymmddhhmm」の文字列をunixtimeに変換

```
unitime='202003020000'
date +%s --date $unitime
結果
date: invalid date ‘202003020000’
```

この結果から、どうもフォーマッティング関数が必要なので探しているのですが見つかりません。
お詳しい方いましたらご助力お願いします。

Comment: 「やりたいこと」の手前の記述は質問と無関係のように見えますが？

Comment: 『「yyyymmddhhmm」の文字列をunixtimeに変換』に関しては、bash であれば `substring expansion` を使って `date +%s --date "${unitime::8} ${unitime:8}"` とする事もできます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「--date」に与える引数が空白を挟んで分割されて「--date 2005-01-01」と「00:00」と別れて解釈されているのが原因です。日付文字列をダブルクォーテーションで囲んであげれば良いと思います。

```
unitime='2005-01-01 00:00' ; date +%s --date "$unitime"
1104505200
```

Answer (score 2):

【回答】
 `yyyymmddhhmm形式`の文字列を`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`形式に変換し、`date +%s --date`を実行するコードです。

【コード】

```
unitime='200501010000'
date_time=$(
  printf "%s" ${unitime} | {
    read -n 4 yyyy
    read -n 2 mm
    read -n 2 dd
    read -n 2 HH
    read -n 2 MM
    printf "%s-%s-%s %s:%s" ${yyyy} ${mm} ${dd} ${HH} ${MM}
  }
)
date +%s --date "${date_time}"
```

【結果】

```
1104505200
```

---

`POSIX complient なシェル`では動かないとの指摘をいただきましたので、sedによる実装例も紹介します。

```
unitime='200501010000'
date_time=$(echo "${unitime}" | sed -n 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5/p')
date +%s --date "${date_time}"
```

Comment: POSIX complient なシェル(例えば dash)では `read` に `-n` オプションがありません。

Comment: 日付や時刻の区切りは必要無さそうなので、`echo "$unittime" | sed "s/\(.\{4\}\)$/ \1/"`で末尾4文字の前にスペースを入れてあげるほうがシンプルかなと思いました。