# シェルの時間文字列（yyyymmddhhMM）を（yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM）のフォーマットに直したいですがうまくいかないです。

Tags: shellscript

シェルの時間文字列（yyyymmddhhMM）を（yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM）のフォーマットに直したいですがうまくいかないです。

時刻を表現している文字列「201901010310」をdateフォーマッテング関数を使っても表示が出てくれません。
以下のコードで何が間違ってフォーマッティングがうまくいってないのかご指摘いただけますと幸いです。

```
nengou_i=201901010310

echo `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" --date "${nengou_i}"`
```

結果
20190101-03-10 00:00:00

本当は以下のように出したい。
2019-01-01 03:10

Comment: [前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66478/4236) での回答の過程で既に手段が提示されています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nengou_i`が数値のみでは20190101年の03月10日と解釈されてしまうので、時刻の前に空白を入れてあげる必要があります。
変数に代入するときに空白を入れることが出来ない場合、以前された [シェルを使ってyyyymmdd形式の変数をunixtimeに変換したい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66478/25936) という質問への[akira-ejiri](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/35558/akira-ejiri)さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/66483/25936)が役に立つと思います。